Uniswap transfer “successful” but not received
I recently sent USDT on the ETH network to another account and I never received it, despite the transaction being labeled successful by Uniswap. The new account hash is correct and yet it still doesn’t show up. I lost my eth fee and all the usdt I sent. If you could help me figure out the problem I would appreciate it!

Can you send the transaction hash oro the address that initiated the transaction?

here is the hash. Thanks for any help! 0xda0086aa3386111c724894c39f8d8bb9a4fcee080d8425072ced4f2f222906bc

The account 0x1D72761b535dF98FA7bbA0126985d5643164243D received 404 USDT in your transaction. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "unsuccessful"?
